# After I melt a polars dataframe, how can I pivot it back to its original form without adding an index?

Tags: python, python-polars

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    'A': range(1,4),
    'B': range(1,4),
    'C': range(1,4),
    'D': range(1,4)
})

print(df)
```

```
shape: (3, 4)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ A   ┆ B   ┆ C   ┆ D   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 1   ┆ 1   ┆ 1   │
│ 2   ┆ 2   ┆ 2   ┆ 2   │
│ 3   ┆ 3   ┆ 3   ┆ 3   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

```py
df_melt = df.melt(
    variable_name="recipe",
    value_name="revenue")

print(df_melt)
```

```
shape: (12, 2)
┌────────┬─────────┐
│ recipe ┆ revenue │
│ ---    ┆ ---     │
│ str    ┆ i64     │
╞════════╪═════════╡
│ A      ┆ 1       │
│ A      ┆ 2       │
│ A      ┆ 3       │
│ B      ┆ 1       │
│ B      ┆ 2       │
│ …      ┆ …       │
│ C      ┆ 2       │
│ C      ┆ 3       │
│ D      ┆ 1       │
│ D      ┆ 2       │
│ D      ┆ 3       │
└────────┴─────────┘
```

It seems I need to add an index in order to pivot `df_melt` back into the original form of `df`? Is there no way to pivot a polars dataframe without adding an index?

```py
df_melt = df_melt.with_columns(index=pl.col("revenue").cum_count().over("recipe"))

df_melt.pivot(
    index='index',
    columns='recipe',
    values='revenue',
    aggregate_function='first'
)
```

```
shape: (3, 5)
┌───────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ index ┆ A   ┆ B   ┆ C   ┆ D   │
│ ---   ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ u32   ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═══════╪═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1     ┆ 1   ┆ 1   ┆ 1   ┆ 1   │
│ 2     ┆ 2   ┆ 2   ┆ 2   ┆ 2   │
│ 3     ┆ 3   ┆ 3   ┆ 3   ┆ 3   │
└───────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

In R, I can perform the equivalent to melt and pivot without indexing, and was seeking the same functionality in Python.

```
df_pandas = df.to_pandas()
```

```
library(tidyverse)
library(reticulate)

df_long <-
    py$df_pandas |>
    pivot_longer(
        everything(),
        names_to = 'recipe',
        values_to = 'value'
    )

df_long |>
    pivot_wider(
        names_from='recipe',
        values_from='value'
    ) |>
    unnest(cols = c(A,B,C,D))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems I need to add an index in order to pivot df_melt back into the original form of df?

How would it otherwise decide that the entries in `df_melt` with `revenue=1` are all on the same row, and not for `recipe=A` the revenue is 2, for `recipe=B`, the revenue is 3, etc? You are inferring that from how you defined `df`, but from just `df_melt` as defined in your question, that is not possible.

If this is a requirement, than I suggest you add the index to `df` before using `melt`, so that `df_melt` carries that information:

```py
>>> df_melt=df.with_row_index().melt(id_vars=["index"], variable_name="recipe",value_name="revenue")  
>>> df_melt
shape: (12, 3)
┌───────┬────────┬─────────┐
│ index ┆ recipe ┆ revenue │
│ ---   ┆ ---    ┆ ---     │
│ u32   ┆ str    ┆ i64     │
╞═══════╪════════╪═════════╡
│ 0     ┆ A      ┆ 1       │
│ 1     ┆ A      ┆ 2       │
│ 2     ┆ A      ┆ 3       │
│ 0     ┆ B      ┆ 1       │
│ 1     ┆ B      ┆ 2       │
│ …     ┆ …      ┆ …       │
│ 1     ┆ C      ┆ 2       │
│ 2     ┆ C      ┆ 3       │
│ 0     ┆ D      ┆ 1       │
│ 1     ┆ D      ┆ 2       │
│ 2     ┆ D      ┆ 3       │
└───────┴────────┴─────────┘
```

The pivot can then use the `index` column to reconstruct the original.

Comment: This is an elegant solution. Thank you. I have updated the OP to show the R functionality to pivot, melt and reverse without indexing. I was thinking the same functionality might be possible in polars.

Answer (score 0):

You can't avoid having an index with `pivot` but you can do a bunch of other stuff in order to do something like a `pivot` without the index. It's probably better to just add the explicit index or, even better, to avoid the melt *but* if you have to have the melt there here's a round trip without adding an index.

```
df_melt = df.melt()
# I skip naming the melt columns since we're round tripping them away.
(
    df_melt
    .group_by('variable', maintain_order=True)
    .agg(pl.col('value'))
    .with_columns(
        pl.col('value').list.to_struct()
    )
    .unnest('value')
    .pipe(lambda zz: (
        zz
        .select(pl.col("^field.*$"))
        .transpose(column_names=zz['variable'])
    ))
)
shape: (3, 4)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ A   ┆ B   ┆ C   ┆ D   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 1   ┆ 1   ┆ 1   │
│ 2   ┆ 2   ┆ 2   ┆ 2   │
│ 3   ┆ 3   ┆ 3   ┆ 3   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

That `pipe` is admittedly pretty awkward because `transpose` doesn't have a built in way to convert the input first column into the output column names.